# div inside a href ruins styling

Tags: html, css, laravel

I use laravel framework. $var->title makes 2 different buttons next to each other.

So i had this code

```
<div class="header-button btn form-control">
   <a href="{{$var->writefullurl}}">
       {{($var->title)}}
   </a>
</div>
```

The code worked fine, except the top and bottom of the button wasn't clickable.

I tried to change the code to this, for some weir reason it ruined the CSS.

```
<a href="{{$var->writefullurl}}">
   <div class="header-button btn form-control">
     {{($var->title)}}
   </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.form-control {
    border-color: #00aae4;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the html that is rendered in the browser? for this: "view source" on any webbrowser (right click).

Comment: i believe your css is not that simple, my guess is that you have something like `div a { bla bla bla }` so when you change the order, the rule does not match anymore

Comment: A few ideas that might be the case: 1) the `div` inside your `a` is a `block element`, but you want `inline-block` 2) Because of [some weird whitespace problems](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) your HTML is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to change the html code order, what you can do is change the element you set the padding such as:

```
.form-control a {
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-control {
    border-color: #00aae4;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

note: make sure to have `display: inline-block` on the `a` tag so that the padding can be applied

Comment: be carefull not to ruin other rules ;)